# Anchors: Scroll to position on page minus the height of the header

Tags: html, css, web

I have a webpage http://www.alexwiley.co.uk/new_site/index.html

As you will see it has a fixed navigation. When you use the navigation it scrolls down the page for you automatically. My issue is that I need it to scroll to a position, for example the 'ABOUT' section, minus the height of the header.

If you look at the page currently you will see that because of the header it overlaps the about title.

Any suggestions or can anybody point me in the correct direction?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Looks OK to me nice looking by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesn't seem to be a fixed header - the navbar scrolls out of view when you go to the section. With fixed nav bars you need to add padding to the top of the body to accomnodate he height of the navbar. This is because it is not part of the dom and page content gets rendered as from the top of the screen and then the fixed element is placed onto th page. If the nav bar (when you do get it fixed) is 50px high, you need to add body{padding-top:50px} to the css whic should allow the correct  offset to the sections when you scroll to them

Comment: Apologies check it out now.

Comment: yup it is the navbar fixed status that is causing that - find tghe height of hte navbar - apply that height to the padding-top in the css for the body and it should fix it.

Comment: Yep this got it! Thanks a lot. I was sort of hoping there was another solution as obviously adding padding can be annoying design wise but oh well.